# System hangs when trying to hibernate on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate, standby

I have an Asus netbook running Windows XP, and lately it randomly hangs when trying to shut down (same for standby). I get the familiar screen `Preparing to hibernate` and then nothing else happens.

How can I fix this?